# Why can't React display the content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I have changes `react-router-dom` where other pages can display the content correctly.
However, I cannot see the content on this page even I change the return elements simply to

## login page

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with it? thank you very much!!

````
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import * as ROUTES from '../constants/routes.js'
import FirebaseContext from '../context/firebase'
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

export default function Login() {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        document.title= "Login - Instagram"
    }, [])
    
    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("")
    const [error, setError] = React.useState("")
    const [pwd, setPwd] = React.useState("")
    const { firebase } = React.useContext(FirebaseContext)
    const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
        username: "",
        password: ""
    })
    
    const isInvalid = values.username === "" || values.password === ""
    
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventdefault()
        const auth = getAuth();
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pwd)
            .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in 
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log(user)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            setEmail('');
            setPwd('');
            setError(error.message);
        });
    }

    console.log(error)
    console.log(firebase)
    
    const handleChange = e => {
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="container flex mx-auto max-w-screen-md items-center h-screen">
            <div className="flex w-3/5">
                <img src="/images/iphone-with-profile.jpg" alt="iPhone with Instagram app" />
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col w-2/5">
                <div className="w-full max-w-xs">
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST" className="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4">
                        <h1 className="flex justify-center w-full">
                            <img src="/public/logo.png" alt="Instagram" className="mt-2 w-6/12 mb-4" />
                        </h1>
                        <input 
                            id="username" 
                            type="text" 
                            name="username"
                            placeholder="Email address" 
                            className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" 
                            value={values.username}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <input 
                            className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" 
                            id="password" 
                            type="password" 
                            placeholder="Password"
                            name="password"
                            value={values.password}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <br />
                        <button 
                            className={`bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded w-full focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline ${isInvalid && 'cursor-not-allowed opacity-50'}`}
                            
                            type="button"
                        >
                        Sign In
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="flex justify-center items-center flex-col w-full bg-white p-4 border">
                    <p className="text-sm">Don't have an account?{` `}
                        <Link to={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} className="font-bold">
                             Sign up
                        </Link>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}```
````

Comment: Protip: Don't use line breaks for layout. That's a misuse of their purpose and clutters your markup. Use wrapper elements instead. It appears that you're using Bootstrap, so use its mechanisms.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. I’m using tailwind in this, is it also applied to it? I’m not sure which code breaks my file.